# Can I write my own custom rule in eslint config?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, rules, any

Is it possible to write custom rule in eslint config?
My case is based on type 'any'. In eslint doc is rule "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any", but it's too strong for me. I want to block assignment like this:

`const dontknow: any = ''; const name: string = dontknow;`

Is it possible to block this case?

Comment: Take a look at this article on how to write custom eslint rules https://flexport.engineering/writing-custom-lint-rules-for-your-picky-developers-67732afa1803

Comment: You can create a custom ESLint rule. But that's too broad to cover here in a satisfactory manner. I would start by reading the ESLint [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules) (which explains it better than anyone on StackOverflow could do). The source code of the rule you mention can be found [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/no-explicit-any.ts). Maybe try to adapt it, play around, and come back here when you have a more specific question to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `no-unsafe-assignment` [rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-assignment) instead of the `no-explicit-any` rule.

> This rule disallows assigning any to a variable, and assigning any[]
> to an array destructuring. This rule also compares the assigned type
> to the variable's type to ensure you don't assign an unsafe any in a
> generic position to a receiver that's expecting a specific type. For
> example, it will error if you assign Set to a variable declared
> as Set.

**.eslintrc**

```
  {
        "root": true,
        "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        "plugins": [
          "@typescript-eslint"
        ],
        "extends": [
          "eslint:recommended",
          "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
          "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
        ],
        "rules": { 
            "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": 2
        },
        "overrides": [
            {
              "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"], // Your TypeScript files extension
              "parserOptions": {
                "project": ["./tsconfig.json"], // Specify it only for TypeScript files
              },
            },
          ],
      }
```